# React Native expo: I'm trying to fetch images url from firebase and put them into array but react native only shows the last item inside array

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jcVE.png)
I can't display the image array that i fetched from firestore

Comment: Consider editing your question to post the code as text instead of as an image.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `Posts` is a `useState` which is an empty array and you are trying to push the elements in it, but you can not push data in an array useState as you did. You are supposed to use JavaScript Spread Operator. Your code should be like this:

```
setPosts(previousState => {
{...previousState, newUserDataArray}
}
```

You can find more details on how to update a `useState` array [here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp).